# How to be notified when a thread has been terminated for some error

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, signals

I am working on a program with a fixed number of threads in C using posix threads.

How can i be notified when a thread has been terminated due to some error?

Is there a signal to detect it?

If so, can the signal handler create a new thread to keep the number of threads the same?

Comment: I'm curious to know if that can be detected without a watchdog thread, but I'm pretty sure you have to leave the "recreation of dead thread" to a thread manager outside the signal handler. (But I've never really tried to do such a thing, so I may be wrong)

Comment: I'm curious to know what you mean by "terminated due to some error". If a thread segfaults the whole process along with all other threads segfaults.

Comment: im working on a multi-threaded webserver, when the number of threads is less than a fixed number, the server terminates. I dont know why threads are being terminated in the program, the server serves about 1000 connections, then it terminates.

Comment: @PavanManjunath linux ubuntu, on a virtual machine

Comment: Are you OK not to bother as to why the thread terminated, error handling etc and just want to start a new thread once the thread count falls below a limit?

Comment: @PavanManjunath yes, i just want to start a new thread once the thread count falls below limit

Comment: @CodeRed, I think that what Pavan was trying to tell you is that if a thread crashes you have a much bigger problem than thread depletion. For example, you are likely to leak memory and other resources, not only that, a crash is often misuse of some memory which another thread could end up attempting to use and in turn crash too. (Unless your threads do not share anything between each others...)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the threads detached
2. Get them to handle errors gracefully. i.e. Close mutexs, files etc...

Then you will have no probolems.

Perhaps fire a USR1 signal to the main thread to tell it that things have gone pear shaped (i was going to say tits up!)

Answer (score 1):

Create your threads by passing the function pointers to an intermediate function. Start that intermediate function asynchronously and have it synchronously call the passed function. When the function returns or throws an exception, you can handle the results in any way you like.

Comment: What if the thread receives a `KILL` signal? ( Or any signal which takes away the control from the `threadFn` asynchronously). The intermediate function cannot handle such cases as the control will be taken away from the `threadFn` asynchronously and it may not return to the intermediate function

Comment: Block all signals for all threads of the process, but one thread which is doing nothing else but a do {sigwaitinfo(); <handle signals>} while (1);. This way your are able to handle asynchronous signals in a threaded manner. @PavanManjunath

Answer (score 1):

With the latest inputs you've provided, I suggest you do something like this to get the number of threads a particular process has started-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define THRESHOLD 50

int main ()
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    FILE *a;

    a = popen ("ps H `ps -A | grep a.out | awk '{print $1}'` | wc -l", "r");
    if (a == NULL)
        printf ("Error in executing command\n");

    fscanf(a, "%d", &count );

    if (count < THRESHOLD)
    {
        printf("Number of threads = %d\n", count-1);
            // count - 1 in order to eliminate header.
            // count - 2 if you don't want to include the main thread

        /* Take action. May be start a new thread etc */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- `ps H` displays all threads.
- `$1` prints first column where PID is displayed on my system Ubuntu. The column number might change depending on the system
- Replace `a.out` it with your process name
- The backticks will evaluate the expression within them and give you the PID of your process. We are taking advantage of the fact that all POSIX threads will have same PID.

Comment: Maybe you could at least use the libprocps rather than a `system()` + `fscanf()` which are rather dangerous functions to use. Also you could look into `gettid()` which gives you the thread identifier (the Linux task id)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt Linux would signal you when a thread dies or exits for any reason. You can do so manually though.

First, let's consider 2 ways for the thread to end:

- It terminates itself
- It dies

In the first method, the thread itself can tell someone (say the thread manager) that it is being terminated. The thread manager will then spawn another thread.

In the second method, a watchdog thread can keep track of whether the threads are alive or not. This is done more or less like this:

```
Thread:
    while (do stuff)
        this_thread->is_alive = true
        work

Watchdog:
    for all threads t
        t->timeout = 0
    while (true)
        for all threads t
            if t->is_alive
                t->timeout = 0
                t->is_alive = false
            else
                ++t->timeout
                if t->timeout > THRESHOLD
                    Thread has died! Tell the thread manager to respawn it
```

Comment: I do agree on the first possiblity ou mention, but for second could you be so kind to explain, what exactly you mean with "it dies", if the thread would have not commited 'suicide', which would be covered by the 1st possiblity, how else would it have ended, if not `pthread_cancel()`ed from the outside?

Comment: @alk, I understand what you are saying. In a Linux user-space application if a thread segfaults (for example) the whole process dies. I don't know if there are operating systems out there where this is not true, but in the very least, in Linux kernel-space a thread can oops without a kernel crash and this is how you would know if it is alive or dead. The question of the OP is "how to know if thread is terminated due to error?". I assume the OP has a more complicated situation at hand than a thread exiting. I do not know what exactly the situation is though so I gave a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason one could not go for Ed Heal's "just work properly"-approach (which is my favorite answer to the OP's question, btw), the lazy fox might take a look at the `pthread_cleanup_push()` and `pthread_cleanup_pop()` macros, and think about including the whole thread function's body in between such two macros.

Answer (score 1):

The clean way to know whether a thread is done is to call `pthread_join()` against that thread.

```
// int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
int retval = 0;
int r = pthread_join(that_thread_id, &retval);
... here you know that_thread_id returned ...
```

The problem with `pthread_join()` is, if the thread never returns (continues to run as expected) then you are blocked. That's therefore not very useful in your case.

However, you may actually check whether you can join (tryjoin) as follow:

```
//int pthread_tryjoin_np(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
int retval = 0;
int r = pthread_tryjoin_np(that_thread_id, &relval);

// here 'r' tells you whether the thread returned (joined) or not.
if(r == 0)
{
   // that_thread_id is done, create new thread here
   ...
}
else if(errno != EBUSY)
{
   // react to "weird" errors... (maybe a perror() at least?)
}
// else -- thread is still running
```

There is also a timed join which will wait for the amount of time you specified, like a few seconds. Depending on the number of threads to check and if your main process just sits around otherwise, it could be a solution. Block on thread 1 for 5 seconds, then thread 2 for 5 seconds, etc. which would be 5,000 seconds per loop for 1,000 threads (about 85 minutes to go around all threads with the time it takes to manage things...)

There is a sample code in the man page which shows how to use the pthread_timedjoin_np() function. All you would have to do is put a for loop around to check each one of your thread.

```
struct timespec ts;
int s;

...

if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1) {
 /* Handle error */
}

ts.tv_sec += 5;

s = pthread_timedjoin_np(thread, NULL, &ts);
if (s != 0) {
   /* Handle error */
}
```

If your main process has other things to do, I would suggest you do not use the timed version and just go through all the threads as fast as you can.